# Suggestions for 'store and forward' of http requests

Tags: https, forwarding

I have the following situation;

- a location only has a few hours of internet connectivity per day.
- this location has however a functioning WiFi network to connect local machines

I need to have a local server that can for a specific web application

- get POST requests and store them, waiting for internet connectivity to appear and then POST all those requests to the actual web server.
- get GET requests and execute + cache them if there is internet connectivity, if there is no internet connectivity; use the cache

This solution would preferably run on Windows ( potentially old versions ) and would have to be free or open source. I am pretty much resigned to write something myself, but I would rather ask this community first.

T.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a transparent proxy (something like Squid) at the router level so that you don't need to worry about client compatibility. I don't know any kind of pre-fabricated solution that would store requests in a queue, though. It would not be *too* difficult to write from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

For GET requests a caching proxy could be configured to serve already cached data.

Most of the POST requests I work with depend a lot on how you navigated to them and are not really cachable in either direction.  POST requests are often used in a sequence controlled by the server.  This makes it extremely difficult to effectively store POST requests.

HTTP was not designed as a store and forward protocol.  For simple GET requests, it is possible and often desirable to cache data to ease load on the network and servers.  Other requests are often non-cacheable.

Comment: I know that HTTP ( especially POST ) was not designed for this, but I was hoping that someone else already had done this. I am planning to put the application logic in javascript without having a server side session so that only the last step is a POST.

Comment: I will not mark you answer as an answer, I am hoping that at some point there will be a ( new ) solution and then I will mark that answer as the one. I did +1 it.